# Android Studio Show backgrounds tasks in the status bar instead of a floating window

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5
```

Every time I build and deploy I get this floating background task appear.

[image]

Normally I click the minimize button to get it to display in the status bar. However, can we change the default behaviour to always show in the status bar.

I couldn't find anything in the settings so not sure if Android Studio designed this way.

I just find this thing annoying.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: How about `Shift+ F12`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Deselect Show and Auto Show into :Window > Background Tasks > Show and Auto Show

[image]