# How can i hide Background Task Screen in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

While I run my application in Android Studio, I see **a Background Task** Screen showing the processes in the application are running. I need help how to remove the screen in future run of my Application.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Perhaps minimzing the windows of tasks? `-` Button on the top-right of the task window?

Comment: Yes it is working. I have figure out. Thanks !

Comment: For some reason, this popup is always shown when I launch anything, and the `-` button does not work, so annoying...

Comment: @David for me it always popped up as well. the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618132/android-studio-show-backgrounds-tasks-in-the-status-bar-instead-of-a-floating-wi

Menu -> Window -> Background Tasks -> uncheck Show, AND uncheck Auto Show as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimize the window of *Background Tasks* by using `-` Button on the top-right of the task window.

> - This will make the window non-visible on the coding side.
> - Also, ***bottom arrow*** with a line under helps to temporary hide a window in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Android Studio Settings]
If you run my application in Android Studio and, see a Background Task Screen showing the processes in the application are running. Then go to Windows -> Background tasks and then Uncheck Show and Auto-Show.